# Como enviar e-mails com HTML e múltiplos destinatários usando SMTP Gmail usando o PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, envio-de-email, email

Como posso habilitar o uso de códigos HTML no corpo do e-mail e permitir o envio para múltiplos destinatários usando quebra de linha no formulário, no código abaixo?

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Configuração para o PHP.INI
 * ------------------------------ */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
 
/* POST
 * ------------------------------ */
if (isset($_POST["Enviar"])) {
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php"); //pastebin.com/QEqmV4i3
    $_SESSION['smtpUsuario'] = $_POST['smtpUsuario'];
    $_SESSION['smtpSenha'] = $_POST['smtpSenha'];
    $_SESSION['from'] = $_POST['from'];
    $_SESSION['Nome'] = $_POST['Nome'];
    $smtpUsuario = $_SESSION['smtpUsuario'];
    $smtpSenha = $_SESSION['smtpSenha'];
    $de_nome        = $_SESSION['Nome'];
    $from        = $_SESSION['from'];
    $Fone        = $_POST["Fone"];
    $subject        = $_POST["subject"];
    $para        = $_POST["para"];
    $Mensagem    = $_POST["Mensagem"];
    $corpo         = ""
            . "$Mensagem\n\n"
            . "Att $de_nome,\n"
            . "$Fone";
    function smtpmailer($para, $from, $de_nome, $subject, $corpo) {
            global $error, $smtpUsuario, $smtpSenha;
            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();        // Ativar SMTP
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;        // Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;        // Autenticação ativada
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';    // SSL REQUERIDO pelo GMail
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';    // SMTP utilizado
            $mail->Port = 587;          // A porta 587 deverá estar aberta em seu servidor
            $mail->Username = $smtpUsuario;
            $mail->Password = $smtpSenha;
            $mail->SetFrom($from, $de_nome);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body = $corpo;
            $mail->AddAddress($para);
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                    $error = '<div class="sent">Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo.'</div>';
                    return false;
            } else {
                    $error = '<div class="sent">Enviado com sucesso!</div>';
                    return true;
            }
    }
    if (smtpmailer($para, $from, $de_nome, $subject, $corpo)) {
        //sent
    }
    if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Nenhuma postagem do site pode depender de links externos. Se quiser, pode [edit] a postagem trazendo as informações relevantes para o site. Ao [edit] a comunidade reavalia e pode reabrir a postagem via voto.

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco! Editado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito simples, mais talvez sua dificuldade seja em programar a solução, e não pensar na mesma ;)

Problema 1:

```
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');
```

Problema 2:

```
$mail->Body = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
```

So precisa saber manipular as variáveis que vão ser passadas para o PHPmailer, exemplo:

Problema 1:

```
$destinatarios = array('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');
$mail->addAddress($destinatarios);
```

Problema 2:

```
$msg_html = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->Body = $msg_html;
```